# Ignore HTML formatting when publishing articles with Confluence Cloud API

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to publish article on Confluence using REST API.

When I am preparing the article in storage format, I indent the content as if I would HTML code, with newlines and spaces. The problem is that when article gets published all these newlines and spaces are preserved, as if I used `<br/>` and non-breaking space symbols.

For example, if I send content like this:

```html
<p>First part of paragraph 
    <ac:link ac:anchor="4b14531b1624f2b">
        <ri:page ri:content-title="Test Article"></ri:page>
        <ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[link caption]]></ac:plain-text-link-body>
    </ac:link>
 last part of paragraph.</p>
```

It is rendered like this on the page:

```
First part of paragraph
    link caption
last part of paragraph.
```

But I expect this:

```
First part of paragraph link caption last part of paragraph.
```

Is it possible to tell confluence to ignore whitespaces as in normal HTML? Maybe there's some setting admins can change?

If I create the page normally through web editor and then get its content by API call, all returned content is on one line. This is stupid.

I never had this problem with previous Confluence servers I worked on.

I am using Confluence Cloud version.

Comment: I don't know the answer or reason for this (I have experience with on-prem Confluence Server only where this is not a problem). But what if you simply remove all the new lines and indentation and pass data as one-line (if you ignore it's stupid as you mentioned:-)? I.e. let all line formatting on `<p>` and `<br/>` elements.

Comment: @CraZ that's what I do, but the problem is that sometimes newlines and spaces are required. For example, in `code` macro, user formatting has to be preserved. I handle that too with some ugly piece of code, but I can't ignore that it is stupid :-D Also there may appear other situations where formatting needs to be preserved and I will have to add yet more ugly code to handle that.